# Перевод с десятичной системы счисления в другие СС

Tags: delphi, системы-счисления

Нужно перевести число с десятичной системы счисления в 2 и до 16.

```
function FromDec(n,r : longint) : string;
    var
      s : string;
    const
      digit:string[16] = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    begin
      s := '';
      repeat
        s := digit[(n mod r)+1] + s;
        n := n div r;
      until n = 0;
      result := s;
    end;
```

Товарищ предложил вот такое решение. Оно работает корректно. Но, я не пойму как это происходит ведь как было показано в лабораторной работе в которой дробная и целая часть числа переводиться по разным правилам и в конечном итоге целая и дробная часть складывается и получается нужное число. То есть перевод целой части тут по правильному алгоритму делается, а дробной не по тому же алгоритму, что в лабе. Как оно так получается?

Comment: Позвольте поинтересоваться, а где в этом коде вообще дробная часть? Код для целых чисел правильный.

Comment: @Jeremen1, как бы, если заглянуть в теоретическую часть перевода чисел из десятичной в другие системы, то там так и есть... Может быть стоит взять учебник почитать?

Comment: А можно в метках язык проставить? А то у меня есть большой соблазн написать ответ на "brainfuck". Спасибо.

Comment: > А то у меня есть большой соблазн написать ответ на "brainfuck"  

а я бы с удовольствием посмотрел  

----  

[KoVadim][1], это же делфи? "result := s", же...

 [1]: http://hashcode.ru/users/2739/kovadim

Comment: это может и паскаль быть. до 2007 делфи (если я правильно помню), язык назывался pascal (object pascal). А потом уже начал называться делфи. Код в 3 делфи скомпилиться, так что все в порядке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не будет этот код для дробной части работать. Условие выхода ведь: n = 0. Ну и вообще, тип входной переменной longint, а не real или extended. Да и в выходной переменной запятая нигде не добавляется.

С чего ты взял, что решение для дробной части работать будет? :)

Comment: я это уже понял. просто в чём смысл был, калькулятор корявые не переводил дроби в другие системы счисления, по этому вводил в калькулятор целое число и проверял как для дроби, оно совпадало, но теперь уже разобрался